# Find string surrounded by specific character, replace the characters but keep the string intact

Tags: regex, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I have several documents that contains variables which need need to be changed from this:

```
@CapitalPx@
```

To this:

```
${CapitalPx}
```

I found out about finding and replacing using regex, and came out with the following one:

```
\@([a-z0-9]+)\@
```

My ultimate goal is to replace what I found with something that would look like the following:

```
\$\{([a-z0-9])\}
```

but it just replaces what I found by this string without interpreting it.

I also tried to find a regex that would match word starting or finishing with '@', but it doesn't work at 100% (LibreOffice seems limited for this)

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do:

- Find: `@(\w+)@`
- Replace: `${$1}`

Check Regular expression.

**Explanation:**

```
@       : literally @
(       : start group 1
  \w+   : 1 or more word character
)       : end group 1
@       : literally @
```